# How do I get count results?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code. Running it directly it is supposed to return 100. But with this code it returns 1. Do I use the ? wrong or why does it return just 1?

```
 <?php

require '../notWebsite/dbh.php';
session_start();
$userID = (int)$_SESSION['userID'];

$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(groupID) FROM savedbyuser WHERE userID = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlCount)) {
header("Location: ../GymnasieArbeteHemsida.php?error=countError");
 exit();
}
else {
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $userID);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$count = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
echo $count;
     exit();
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);



?>
```

Comment: Use session start at the first line.  You have any error ?

Comment: You are looking at the return value of `mysqli_stmt_execute` which returns a bool depending on if the statement executed - so it is actually returning true which is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as stated in manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

```
Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
```

so this

```
$count = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
echo $count;
```

translates to

```
$count = true;
echo $count;
// print 1
```

in manual focus on

```
Note:

When using mysqli_stmt_execute(), the mysqli_stmt_fetch() function must be used to fetch the data prior to performing any additional queries.
```

leads to https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php and so on...